# what server settings required for removing the # in a angular spa

Tags: angularjs, hyperlink, single-page-application

So, I read a couple of books about angular 1 and I impement their examples about creating an SPA. The code is like

```
  var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);        
            app.config(function ($routeProvider) {          
                $routeProvider                                     
                .when('/', {                      
                   templateUrl: 'home.html',                         
                   controller: 'homeController'                    
               })                    
                .when('/about', {                     
                   templateUrl: 'about.html',                        
                   controller: 'aboutController'                    
               })                    
                .when('/contact', {                                              
                   templateUrl: 'contact.html',                         
                   controller: 'contactController'                    
                   })                    
                .otherwise({                      
                   templateUrl: 'routeNotFound.html',                         
                   controller: 'notFoundController'                    
               });        

         });
```

and the liks are

```
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>                
            <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>                
            <li><a href="#contact""><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
```

All books say that I can get rid of the # character in the links by setting the location provider like so

`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

in the `app.config` and also the links like

`<a href="/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a>`

But all books also say that there are some modifications needed to be done server-side in order to support this kind of links.

What are those modifications? How can I implement them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need to be sure that your server is still outputting `index.html` even for such requests:

```
/categories/users/123
```

(i.e. does not try to go inside non-existent folders categories/users/123)

Answer (score 1):

If you configure $location to use `html5Mode` `(history.pushState)`, you need to specify the base URL for the application with a `<base href="">` tag or configure `$locationProvider` to not require a base tag by passing a definition object with `requireBase:false` to `$locationProvider.html5Mode()`:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});
```

No server side changes needed. Angular SPA not send requests to `/about` or `/contact` like urls, just load templates. But if you want to make your app visible for web crawlers and search bots, you should prepare server side rendering by using `PhantomJS` or `AngularJS-Server`

Comment: It worked for me when I added `$locationProvider.html5Mode({enable:true, requireBase:false});` . Now the problem is that when I type `http://localhost:8383/about` I get an empty response. How can I fix this ? Should I use PhantomJS or AngularJS-Server ? Thanks

Comment: You should use server side rendering just for crawlers. To make url like `http://localhost:8383/about` working, set server side route on this request to root page.